# Cannot access Flask app running in container from macOS M1 local host machine

Tags: docker, docker-compose, apple-silicon

I am trying to run a simple Flask app in a container from my Apple Silicon macOS. However, I am unable to access the started Flask app (app starts without issues inside container) from the mac host at `localhost:5000`.

Can someone please help with this. I tried other solutions online but none worked. Can this be an issue with Mac and Docker?

`docker-compose.yml` file is:

```
version: '3'

services:
  basic_app:
    build:
        context: .
        dockerfile: Dockerfile
    #network_mode: host -> not needed
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
    command: bash -c "flask run --host=0.0.0.0 --port=5000"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`network_mode: host` [doesn't work on MacOS](https://docs.docker.com/network/host/), and should almost never be necessary in general.  Delete that line.

Trying to enable host networking on Docker Desktop setups will prevent this application from working, even though you've checked the other boxes (server process listening on 0.0.0.0, published `ports:`).  You should get a warning that `ports:` and host networking are incompatible, because host networking is an instruction to disable Docker's networking layer.

(Technically the process is running on the host network of a hidden Linux VM, but without the `ports:` wiring functioning, you can't access it from the MacOS host.)

Comment: Sorry, I missed the part that host networking does not work on MacOS.


@David Maze, so this means that it is not possible to access a web-service type app from MacOS. That is a bummer. I wonder if all such apps are developed on linux VMs etc.

Comment: You especially do not need host networking for a normal Web-service-type application.  The normal `docker run -p` option or Compose `ports:` will publish a port out to the host system the way you expect.  The only times it's necessary are if the application listens on thousands of ports, or on unpredictable ports, or needs to break the container abstraction in some way, and none of these are true for a typical HTTP-serving application.

Answer (score 0):

app.py

```
if __name__=="__main__":
port = int(os.environ.get('PORT', 80))
print(f"Port: {port}")
app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=port)
```

docker-compose.yaml

```
ports:
  - "80:80"
```

Dockerfile

```
CMD ["python3", "app.py"]
```

Now do docker-compose down, docker-compose build and docker-compose up. That's how I solved it on MacOS.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: lol it is clear enough